# Why won't my iframes load in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a little code here that detects if its a mobile browser or desktop browser. That works, but I'm trying to provie different iframes based on browser and the iframes aren't loading. Please help/fix!

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        /* Storing user's device details in a variable*/
        let details = navigator.userAgent;
  
        /* Creating a regular expression 
        containing some mobile devices keywords 
        to search it in details string*/
        let regexp = /android|iphone|kindle|ipad/i;
  
        /* Using test() method to search regexp in details
        it returns boolean value*/
        let isMobileDevice = regexp.test(details);
  
        if (isMobileDevice) {
            document.write("You are using a Mobile Device");
        } else {
<iframe target="_parent" src="https://google.com/" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a PHP version but no luck. Please help!

Comment: You've included the iFrame's html tag in the javascript. You need to build it in JS, either via `document.createElement()` or `innerHTML` or you can start with it hidden in your html  and use JS to display it.

Answer (score -1):

**This is the solution if the device has detect if the user agent is mobile will throw an incompatible device message otherwise will proceed to browser activity even though if they enable desktop mode in their mobile browser there is a incompatible message remains**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #root {
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #browser {
        border: 0;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let device = navigator.userAgent;
    let isMobile = device.includes("Android") || device.includes("iPhone") || device.includes("iPad");
    let root = document.querySelector("#root");

    let message = () => {
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = "You are using a mobile device.";
        root.appendChild(p);
    };

    let browser = () => {
        let browser = document.createElement("iframe");
        browser.id = "browser";
        browser.target = "_parent";
        browser.src = "https://bing.com";
        browser.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        root.appendChild(browser);
    }

    if (isMobile) {
        message();
    } else {
        browser();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And you can use a ternary operator alternative of IF ELSE statement.**

```
isMobile ? message() : browser();
```